# Edittext gettext tostring shows error on setOnClickListener

Tags: android, onclick

My `SignUpActivity` class shows `NullPointerException` at `getText().toString()` on `mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener`.

SignUpActivity:

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;


        public class SignUpActivity extends Activity {

            protected EditText mUsername;
            protected EditText mPassword;
            protected EditText mEmail;
            protected Button mSignUpButton;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

            mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usenameField);
            mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
            mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
            mSignUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupButton);



            mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                    String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

                    username = username.trim();
                    password = password.trim();
                    email = email.trim();

                    if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.sign_up_error_message)
                            .setTitle(R.string.sign_up_error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        // create the new user!
                    }
                }
            });
        }




        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_up, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

*this is my logcat file*

```
02-26 14:00:26.288: D/AndroidRuntime(19215): Shutting down VM
02-26 14:00:26.289: W/dalvikvm(19215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414589a8)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at com.turtalabs.bagit.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:32)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4243)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17520)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-26 14:00:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(19215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*my layout file*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SignUpActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usernameField"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signupButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please provide logcat?

Comment: Do you have R.id.emailField on your layout?

Comment: check if all of your Text Fields are present in layout.

Comment: how did you know that the error comes from get.Text().toString(); ?

Comment: Can you post your activity_sign_up xml file?

Comment: What is the line 32 in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that in your layout file this element is called "use**r**nameField"?

```
mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usenameField);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a silly mistake. I am not able to remove it from my R. java file.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace this

```
mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usenameField);
```

With

```
mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
```

Because of this silly mistake `Activity` not finding `EditText` with `mUsername`.